# Symfony Doctrine related error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

We have a project handed over to us in the form of code, we are seeing the following error when trying to check the content:

Error:

> appDevDebugProjectContainer::getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService(): Failed opening required '/srv/var/cache/dev/jms_diextra/doctrine/EntityManager_5950bc388c29e.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /srv/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line N

Can anyone let us know your view on this issue? And possible ways to resolve it.

Comment: You should try cleaning the cache content

Comment: As @ste suggested - this is a cache related issue. Simply remove `/srv/var/cache/dev` manually or use `php bin/console.php cache:clear`.

Comment: Thanks will give it a try and let you know the feedback

Comment: @tftd Still the same issue. Steps followed  1. log into docker for php and delete the Dev folder'  2.  rebuild using docker-compose build and restart the service. kindly suggest something that would help.

Comment: You should have mentioned that you're using Docker. :) What image are you using in `Docker`?

Comment: Sorry for that, I should have mentioned. the code is a variant of https://github.com/intellectsoft-uk/symfony-skeleton

Comment: I suspect this might be a permission problem. Try creating a container with the image and then logging in to `chmod -R 777 /srv/var/{cache,logs,sessions}`

Comment: @tftd Thanks for your time on this. It doesn't seem to be a permission issue as the test environment is able to create these cache folder content, do you know when does this cache get generated some link on the content would help

Comment: The cache folder `/srv/var/cache/{prod}` is created the first time you access your website and then it's used until it expires or you force clean it. As for `cache/{dev,test}` they are usually refreshed upon each request to the site. I'm not sure what's the problem here but it seems to be related to `jms/di-extra-bundle`. You might get better answer posting an issue here https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/issues